# How to get keycode even if the keycode is being overridden in by a different script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keycode

I'm writing a web extension in javascript that is supposed to run alongside vimium. It uses a key combination to enter a mode where it listens for numbers. The problem is that vimium blocks number keys unless it itself is in input mode. Is there anyway to steal the focus away from vimium?

Comment: As far as I know Viumium doesn't provide an API... Your extension is "extending" vimium? I mean it depends on it? Or it's a conflict issue...  because you can report that on their github project too.

Comment: It's not extending it. I just intend for it to be used at the same time. I need to grab focus somehow, while vimium is running in normal mode so that I can send keys to my extension, instead. Maybe I could append a div to the document body then give it focus and send keys to that?